# Write a dat file from 2D complex numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let's say that I have a 2D complex numpy array as the following:

```
import numpy as np
xl=np.linspace(0,2,num=3)
yl=np.linspace(0,1,num=2)
xm,ym=np.meshgrid( xl, yl, sparse=True, indexing='ij' )
z=xm**2+1j*ym
print(z)
```

How can I export the 2D array into a dat file in the following form?

```
  x    y    Re(z)   Im(z)
  0    0     0       0
  0    1     0       1
  1    0     1       0
  1    1     1       1
  2    0     4       0
  2    1     4       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd

x, y = np.indices(z.shape, sparse=True)
x, y = x.ravel(), y.ravel()

data = []
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        n = z[i][j]
        data.append((i, j, n.real, n.imag))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns='x y Re(z) Im(z)'.split())
df = df.astype(int)
print(df.to_csv(index=False, sep='\t'))
```

Prints:

```
x       y       Re(z)   Im(z)
0       0       0       0
0       1       0       1
1       0       1       0
1       1       1       1
2       0       4       0
2       1       4       1
```